# Only my website footer shows up in print previews?

Tags: css, printing, web

Thanks for your help on this. I have been brought in on a project working on a large education  site that I was not responsible for developing. There are plenty of issues but the most interesting is that, in every browser I've tried (ie8+, FF2+, Chrome), the site contents will not show up in a print preview. All I get is the footer.  The original developer is no longer on the project but the site is still very much in beta. 
[See here](http://beta.lowercolumbia.edu/)

Hit Ctrl + P and see for yourself. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, worked on this for days and found the problem.

This plus a few strategic "display:none;" tags solved it:

```
  @media print{
  body background-color:#FFFFFF; background-image:none; color:#000000;
  #ad display:none;
  #leftbar display:none;
  #contentarea width:100%;
 }
```

Thanks to [javascriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia2.shtml) for the solution.